# How do I use the Sticky Footer CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've taken a look at the sticky footer CSS and have tried to make changes to my CSS so I could get this concept but no luck as I can't change html & body to 100% height.

[Here's the sticky footer CSS that I'd like](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

[And here's the link to my web page that I'd like it on](http://redsky.incredifull.com/)

& Here's my CSS

```
/* Main content styles */

body {
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Regular;
}

html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

/* Container */
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
}

/* Content */
#content {
width: 642px;
float: right;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#content h1 {
padding: 0 0 20px 0;
margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #94b9c4;
}

.article {
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.articleimg {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
}


/* Footer */
#footer {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
 width: 642px;
 float: right;
 clear: both;
}

   #footer p {
           font-family: Helvetica Neue: Regular;
       font-size: 12px;
           color: #94b9c4;
           padding: 10px 0 0 0;
           margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
           border-top: 1px solid #94b9c4;
   }
```

Comment: too much code and not enough explaining what you mean please edit

Comment: Edited the code but not sure how to make it more known what I'd like help with because it states it right there. I'd like to know how to use the sticky footer css and Ive given a link to it... It just doesn't seem to work when I put "html, body height: 100%"....

Answer (score 1):

The only code that is important when using a sticky footer with CSS is the position attribute for the footer. In the HTML, make sure that the footer div is a child of the body:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

The reason it needs to be a child of the body is because `position` in CSS is based on the positioning of its closest ancestor. If you position the footer absolutely within another `<div>` than you always have to be cognizant about that containers position. Anyway, the CSS should be like so:

**CSS**

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; // remove this if you have a specified width for the footer
    right: 0; // remove this too
    height: 100px; // you can change this
}
```

The previous code should create a footer that spans the whole bottom of the page with 100px height. This will stick the footer to the bottom of the page no matter what. However, you must also keep in mind that this footer will need to be accounted for so that it does not cover your content. I typically will add a padding on the bottom of my content area roughly the same as the height of my footer. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think together we covered both relevant cases. :)

Comment: Yeah, most definitely :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this footer you use in your question will work, let me show you another way, that uses less code in both CSS and HTML. This will create a footer, that is sticky to the bottom of the viewport or the content, depending which is longer. So this one is not fixed.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Any content without the need of a wrapper</h1>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    /* the margin compensates the footer's height plus and margin if you want one */
    margin: 0 0 100px 0;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/F43fd/)

Answer (score 0):

on your page, keep  as the child of the body. for example:

```
<body>
    <div class="main"> 
        <p>"paragraph"</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Created by </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

in css file

```
body {
  .
  .
  .
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```